# Why Javascript menu opens only once when you click on the button?

Tags: javascript, html, css, menu

I'm trying to build a sidenav that appears and disappears when the button is clicked. For now it works halfway. When you click the button it opens, if you click it again it closes, but then it never reopens.

Can anyone help me figure out what I'm doing wrong? Sorry, I'm new and I'm trying to learn. So far I have followed the suggestions of stack users and have come to this result.

I appreciate any response, thanks.

Ps: as it is just a test there are some classes that I am not using and that I will have to delete.

```js
    var menu = document.querySelector(".mob_menu_button");
      function mobile_menu(e) {
      
        e.stopPropagation(); 
        var x = document.getElementById("sidenav");
        if (!x.classList.contains("active")) {
          x.classList.add("active");
          menu.innerHTML = "<span>Close Menu<span>";
        } 
      }
      
      document.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
        var x = document.getElementById("sidenav");
        if (e.target.id !== "sidenav" && x.classList.contains("active")) {
          x.classList.add("hide");
          menu.innerHTML = "<span>Open menu</span>";
        }
      });
```

```css
body {
  background: #686a81;
}

/*Overlay*/
#overlay {
    position: fixed;
    height: 100vh;
    top: 0;
    background: #000;
    z-index: 999;
}

#overlay.bgover {
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #000000d1;
}

/*Toggle Button*/
 .mob_menu_button {
       display: flex;
       align-content: center;
       justify-content: center;
       align-items: center;
       width: 100%;
       background: #282c33!important;
       font-weight: 500!important;
      }

/*Sidebar*/
.sidenav_box {
}

.menu {
  width: 70%;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #fbfbfb;
  box-shadow: 5px 0px 15px 0px #00000021;
  }

#sidenav {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left:-100%;
    transition: 0.9s;
    z-index: 1000;
}

#sidenav.active {
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background: #00000094; 
}

#sidenav.hide {
    left: -100%; 
}

/*Items menu*/
.user_menu {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

/*Menu header info*/
.display.name {
   font-size: 15px;
   font-weight: 500;
   color: #303238;
}

.display.mail {
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #3d5afe;
}

hr.solid {
    border-top: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
    margin: 10px 0px 10px 0px;
}

/*Text Link css*/
.user_menu.item > a {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 8px 0;
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #75777d;
}

.user_menu.item:hover > a {
    color: #2e323a;
}

.mts_mob_container.active {
        display: flex;
        position: fixed;
        z-index: 999;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        background: #000000d6;
        height: 100vh;
      }
```

```html
<button onclick="mobile_menu(event)" class="mob_menu_button">Open menu</button>

<div id="sidenav">
 <div class="sidenav_box"> 
 
 <div class="menu">
 {%  if function( 'is_user_logged_in') %}
    <div class="user_menu header">
        <span class="display name">Ciao [display_name]</span>
        <span class="display mail">[display_email]</span>
    </div>   
 {% else %}
    <div>prov</div>
            
 {% endif %}
     <hr class="solid">  
     
    <div class="user_menu item">
        <a href="/account">
         <i class="icn_menu fa-regular fa-user"></i>
         <span class="link_text">Dashboard</span>
        </a>
    </div>
    
     <div class="user_menu item">
        <a href="ordini">
         <i class="icn_menu fa-regular fa-basket-shopping"></i>
         <span class="link_text">I miei ordini</span>
        </a>
    </div>
    
    <div class="user_menu item">
        <a href="libreria">
         <i class="icn_menu fa-regular fa-cloud-arrow-down"></i>
         <span class="link_text">Downloads</span>
        </a>
    </div>
    
    <div class="user_menu item">
        <a href="impostazioni">
         <i class="icn_menu fa-regular fa-gear"></i>
         <span class="link_text">Impostazioni</span>
        </a>
    </div>
    
    <div class="user_menu item">
        <a href="wp-login.php?action=logout">
         <i class="icn_menu fa-regular fa-arrow-right-from-bracket"></i>
         <span class="link_text">Logout</span>
        </a>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to add `x.classList.remove("active");` instead of `x.classList.add("hide");` in

```
 document.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
        var x = document.getElementById("sidenav");
        if (e.target.id !== "sidenav" && x.classList.contains("active")) {
          x.classList.add("hide");
          menu.innerHTML = "<span>Open menu</span>";
        }
});
```

Comment: I have already tried, but in this way the transition of .3s in the css only works when the menu appears, instead when it disappears the transition does not work. So I wanted to change the method by choosing to add a hide class which hides the menu.

Comment: in this case u need to toggle betwwen hide and active so in your button click function change `x.classList.add("active");` to `x.classList.add("active");x.classList.remove("hide");` and in "document.addEventListener" do the opposite

Comment: so in "document.addEventListener" instead of `x.classList.add("hide");` you should put `x.classList.add("hide");x.classList.remove("active");`

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I really appreciate. I just tried, the slide works, but transition 0.3 still fails. The transition is there when the menu appears, but it is not there when it disappears.

Comment: Now it's working. The transition error occurred because I had width: 100%; on # sidenav.active instead of #sidenav

Answer (score 0):

```js
    var menu = document.querySelector(".mob_menu_button");
      function mobile_menu(e) {
      
        e.stopPropagation(); 
        var x = document.getElementById("sidenav");
        if (!x.classList.contains("active")) {
          x.classList.add("active");
          menu.innerHTML = "<span>Close Menu<span>";
        } 
      }
      
      document.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
        var x = document.getElementById("sidenav");
        if (e.target.id !== "sidenav" && x.classList.contains("active")) {
          x.classList.add("hide");
          menu.innerHTML = "<span>Open menu</span>";
        }
      });
```

```css
body {
  background: #686a81;
}

/*Overlay*/
#overlay {
    position: fixed;
    height: 100vh;
    top: 0;
    background: #000;
    z-index: 999;
}

#overlay.bgover {
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #000000d1;
}

/*Toggle Button*/
 .mob_menu_button {
       display: flex;
       align-content: center;
       justify-content: center;
       align-items: center;
       width: 100%;
       background: #282c33!important;
       font-weight: 500!important;
      }

/*Sidebar*/
.sidenav_box {
}

.menu {
  width: 70%;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #fbfbfb;
  box-shadow: 5px 0px 15px 0px #00000021;
  }

#sidenav {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left:-100%;
    transition: 0.9s;
    z-index: 1000;
}

#sidenav.active {
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background: #00000094; 
}

#sidenav.hide {
    left: -100%; 
}

/*Items menu*/
.user_menu {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

/*Menu header info*/
.display.name {
   font-size: 15px;
   font-weight: 500;
   color: #303238;
}

.display.mail {
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #3d5afe;
}

hr.solid {
    border-top: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
    margin: 10px 0px 10px 0px;
}

/*Text Link css*/
.user_menu.item > a {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 8px 0;
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #75777d;
}

.user_menu.item:hover > a {
    color: #2e323a;
}

.mts_mob_container.active {
        display: flex;
        position: fixed;
        z-index: 999;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        background: #000000d6;
        height: 100vh;
      }
```

```html
<button onclick="mobile_menu(event)" class="mob_menu_button">Open menu</button>

<div id="sidenav">
 <div class="sidenav_box"> 
 
 <div class="menu">
 {%  if function( 'is_user_logged_in') %}
    <div class="user_menu header">
        <span class="display name">Ciao [display_name]</span>
        <span class="display mail">[display_email]</span>
    </div>   
 {% else %}
    <div>prov</div>
            
 {% endif %}
     <hr class="solid">  
     
    <div class="user_menu item">
        <a href="/account">
         <i class="icn_menu fa-regular fa-user"></i>
         <span class="link_text">Dashboard</span>
        </a>
    </div>
    
     <div class="user_menu item">
        <a href="ordini">
         <i class="icn_menu fa-regular fa-basket-shopping"></i>
         <span class="link_text">I miei ordini</span>
        </a>
    </div>
    
    <div class="user_menu item">
        <a href="libreria">
         <i class="icn_menu fa-regular fa-cloud-arrow-down"></i>
         <span class="link_text">Downloads</span>
        </a>
    </div>
    
    <div class="user_menu item">
        <a href="impostazioni">
         <i class="icn_menu fa-regular fa-gear"></i>
         <span class="link_text">Impostazioni</span>
        </a>
    </div>
    
    <div class="user_menu item">
        <a href="wp-login.php?action=logout">
         <i class="icn_menu fa-regular fa-arrow-right-from-bracket"></i>
         <span class="link_text">Logout</span>
        </a>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).